# What does TLV stand for?

Tags: lightning-network, terminology, lightning-routing, ln-gossip

I'm reading about the gossip protocol and wanted to know what a TLV is. I can't find what it means anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

TLV stands for [type-length-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value). It's an encoding scheme used when protocols allow for optional elements in their messages.

The **type** is a label telling you what field you're looking at, the **length** tells you how long the field is, and the **value** provides the actual field data.